# map documentation not clear enough

Tags: perl

I've tried to understand the map function by reading its documentation to no avail.
In the documentation it says `"Evaluates the BLOCK or EXPR for each element of LIST"`
However, how is one to know that one can also use file test operators as well as shown below?

```
map { [$_, -s] } ('perl.c', 'sv.c', 'hv.c', 'av.c');
```

Source of the above code is: http://www.stllinux.org/meeting_notes/1997/0918/schwtr.html

So basically, the result will be a hash of files along with its file size but how on earth was I supposed to know about this from the documentation alone?

Can you guys help me out to understand more?

Comment: Not a hash of files. This code generate a list of array reference. See anonymous array if you are lost.

Comment: Though you could return a hash of filename to size mapping if you return an array instead of an arrayref from the block, and assign to a hash.

Comment: @edi_allen, yes i should've stated array reference, i wrote my question late at night.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Actually, it says

> map BLOCK LIST
>
> Evaluates the BLOCK or EXPR for each element of LIST (**locally setting
>   $_ to each element**) and returns the list value composed of the results
>   of each such evaluation. In scalar context, returns the total number
>   of elements so generated. Evaluates BLOCK or EXPR in list context, so
>   each element of LIST may produce zero, one, or more elements in the
>   returned value.

The important part is that `$_` is localized to the BLOCK, containing the value of each element of the LIST. Much the same is true for a `for` loop, i.e. `for (LIST)`.

The `-s` function is as you say a file test, and without explicit argument it operates on `$_`. This is the same default behaviour that many of Perl's built-in functions have, for example `print`, `unpack`, `ord`, `length`.

The code you are showing contains a single scalar expression: `[$_, -s]`, which is an array ref containing the file name inside `$_` and as you say, its size.

So, basically, what you are seeing here is basic Perl techniques. If there is anything that is still not clear, feel free to ask.

**Update:**

As for what this code in specific does, it is probably part of a [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform), whereby you perform a more efficient sort on a list, where the sort criteria consists of an expensive operation. For example:

```
my @files = ('perl.c', 'sv.c', 'hv.c', 'av.c');
my @sorted = sort { -s $a <=> -s $b } @files;     # sorting by file size
```

For a small list, this will not matter much, but with a larger list, it might not be very efficient to run file tests multiple times, so instead we cache the test result in an array ref:

```
my @sorted = map $_->[0],                    # restore original value
             sort { $a->[1] <=> $b->[1] }    # perform sort on element #2
             map { [ $_, -s ] } @files;      # your map statement
```

And this is then called a [Schwartzian transform](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartzian_transform).

Comment: It's making more sense now, but how would you know that expression [$_,-s] would have worked the way it does? The way that these built-in functions work is for example:$filesize = -s $filename; I guess the question is how would anybody have known that the -s function works the way it does in the array ref as opposed to the normal way it normally does as in the example above.

Comment: The way you know is by looking up [file tests](http://perldoc.perl.org/functions/-X.html) in the manual. :) "If the argument is omitted, tests $_..."

Comment: @david: Not everyone makes so much use of `$_` as the default argument, because it easier to see what that code is doing when an argument is provided (even if that would be a non-required `-s $_` in the code). Although it is still a valid style choice, really heavy use of implicit `$_` is not so common, precisely because it causes you to need to know the default behaviour or check the manual.

Comment: @NeilSlater I don't understand that sort of thinking. If I don't know what `-s` does, would I then know what `-s $file` does? And if I know that `-s` is a file test, would I then *not* know that it operates on a file, and that every other function in Perl uses `$_` when no argument is given? I think in a limited scope like this, using implicit `$_` is rather nice looking. Such as `say for @list`, or `@dirs = grep -d, @files`.

Comment: @TLP: Personally I'd probably use explicit `[$_, -s $_]` in that code, but would be happy to see the condensed version. The "thinking" (or more accurately "guessing") is in fact that many developers will have get a 2-second pause to mentally recall knowledge of Perl default, even if they know what `-s` does, and about magic use of `$_` in general. It's not a big deal on a neat little map like in the question, but in practice you don't see it across longer stretches of code, even though it would work. I don't usually see `print;` sat on it's own outside of "playful" code.

Comment: @NeilSlater, I finally see the light!thanks so much for your help. What helped me understand was teh code [$_, -s] == [$_, -s $_] ! now i do understand that -s was not operating on the $_ before the comma but rather on the normal way that Perl works when there is no explicit argument. Thanks so much once again!

Comment: @david You did not get that when I said `The -s function is as you say a file test, and without explicit argument it operates on $_.` ? I thought it was obvious that it was a list of two elements, `$_` and the return value of `-s`. Anyway.. if you are happy with the answer, you can accept the answer by clicking the checkmark beside it.

Comment: yeah, i understood that but i thought for some weird reason that the file test was using the special variable $_ from inside the hash ref [ $_, -s ] when in fact is not the case at all. I guess I was wrongly interpreting your answer.

Comment: @david Then my explanation of Schwartzian transform must have been very confusing.

Comment: @TLP,I had read the explanation for the transform from the URL and it's pretty straight forward after I finally understood what the map function is doing. I'm using the perl debugger to run each part of the algorithm as well. It was very confusing to understand it initially though.I starting writing scripts in Perl 5 years ago, but I see a have a lot to learn! Thanks for your explanation though it really helped me a lot. Basically, I have to sort out time in the following format hh:mm:ss.ms with other fields but I think this transform will help me a lot.